# DecisionTreeClassifier vs ExtraTreeClassifier

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm trying to figure out which decision tree method from scikit-learn package will better suit my needs for performing classification task.

However, I found that there are two decision tree models available there:

- standard *DecisionTreeClassifier* based on optimized CART algorithm from scikit.tree package.
- ensemble method *ExtraTreeClassifier* from scikit.ensemble package.

Can anyone specify the advantages and disadvatages of using each of these models?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`ExtraTreeClassifier` is an extremely randomized version of `DecisionTreeClassifier` meant to be used internally as part of the `ExtraTreesClassifier` ensemble.

[Averaging ensembles](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#forests-of-randomized-trees) such as a `RandomForestClassifier` and `ExtraTreesClassifier` are meant to tackle the variance problems (lack of robustness with respect to small changes in the training set) of individual `DecisionTreeClassifier` instances.

If your main goal is maximizing prediction accuracy you should almost always use an ensemble of decision trees such as `ExtraTreesClassifier` (or alternatively a [boosting ensemble](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#adaboost)) instead of training individual decision trees.

Have a look at the original [Extra Trees paper](http://orbi.ulg.ac.be/bitstream/2268/9357/1/geurts-mlj-advance.pdf) for more details.